# Почему новичок — "чайник"?

Tags: этимология, жаргон, пунктуация

Всем известна серия книг в черно-желтой обложке "Для чайников". "Чайником" называют новичка в чем-то, еще ничего не умеющего.
А откуда вообще пошла такая традиция? Почему именно чайник? И надо ли, кстати, это слово брать в кавычки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Версий - много, достоверных - нет.

Наиболее правдоподобная, на мой взгляд, автомобильная. Новичок за рулём - чисто чайник. Свистит, пыхтит, аккумулятор кипит...

Перечислять версии лениво, любой поисковик выдаст их десятками.
Хотя бы здесь.
http://subscribe.ru/archive/history.signs/201004/02145450.html

Но на самом деле все подобные версии страдают одним недостатком. Чайник ("Тea-pot") - совсем не только русское. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utah_teapot
Там есть и некая объясняющая версия. 
Чайник - типичный объект для тренировки для начинающих художников. В том числе - и  компьютерных.

Answer (score 5):

Насколько я помню, это пошло из лыжного спорта. Когда инструктор объяснял новичкам, как надо кататься на лыжах, эти самые новички стояли, держа одну руку на поясе, а второй упершись в дерево. С виду такая поза смахивает на чайник. Оттуда это сленговое обозначение новичком перебралось в другие сферы жизни.

Answer (score 2):

Я встречался с другой туристической версией.

Когда еще были рюкзаки, как надутые мешки-шары, и их новички неправильно носили - отпуская лямки и неся вес на пояснице-крестце, то со стороны это напоминало чайник. Сам рюкзак - емкость, а наклоненное вперед тело - носик чайника.

Answer (score 1):

Личное мнение:

Когда-то компьютер был редкость, и требовалось коллективное мышление. Чтобы было меньше вопросов, новичкам говорили: "Принеси-ка чайку".

Отсюда - "чайник".

Answer (score 1):

Как уже сказали в самом вопросе, "чайником" называют новичка ничего не умеющего, только-только приступающего к изучению чего-либо.
Конечно, есть какая-то самая первая версия этого шуточного прозвища неопытного человека. Скорее всего, пошло оно от туристов и альпинистов, с самыми разными вариациями:

- «чайник любит фотографироваться в традиционной позе: одна рука уперта в бок, другая приветственно помахивает фотографу»
- версия с рюкзаком старого типа "мешок" и подсовывание новичку настоящего чайника, вещь громоздкую и тяжёлую.

Затем пошли новички-водители, у которых на стекле был приклеен знак в виде буквы У, сейчас это восклицательный знак. А далее другие, набирающие популярность интересные сферы из нашей жизни.

В общем-то неважно, какая из версий самая первая, прозвище необидное и зачастую сами новички называют себя именно так, чтобы сказать о своей некомпетентности в той или иной области знаний, в частности обращаясь за помощью к более опытным людям.

PS: спасибо за грамматические правки Артёму Луговому, старался, но увы, всё же "наследил" :D

Answer (score 0):

В 80-е годы прошлого столетия))) я слышал такую версию: если чайник поставить на край донышка и катнуть, то покатится он в неизвестно-непредсказуемом направлении. Так и неопытный водитель ведёт себя иногда на дороге. В то время таких как сейчас цилиндрообразных чайников не было.)))